# Calculate $\sigma$ from the tensor equation $ \sigma + S \, [S:\sigma] = C$

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I have a tensor equation:

$${\boldsymbol \sigma} + {\bf S} \, [{\bf S}:{\boldsymbol \sigma}] = {\bf C} \tag{1}$$

I want to calculate ${\boldsymbol \sigma}$, whereas $\bf S$ and $\bf C$ are known constant second-order tensors. The easiest try would be to :
$${\boldsymbol \sigma} + {\bf S} \, [{\bf S}:({\bf I \cdot \boldsymbol \sigma})] = {\bf C} $$

$$[\bf I + {\bf S} \, \otimes {\bf S}: \bf I ]\cdot{\boldsymbol \sigma} = {\bf C} $$

$${\boldsymbol \sigma} = {[\bf I + {\bf S} \, \otimes {\bf S}: \bf I ]}^{-1}\cdot {\bf C} $$

but when I calculated the result manually with indices, the result was different, so this approach seems definitely wrong.

My question is: is it possible to factor out $\boldsymbol \sigma$ from the left hand side of equation $(1) $?

Is there any alternate way to accomplish this task of calculating a tensor from such expression (which contains double contraction)?.

**Edit**: using fourth order identity tensor, defined by:
$$\mathbb I = {\mathbb I}^{-1}$$
and 
$$\mathbb I : \boldsymbol \sigma = \boldsymbol \sigma$$
*is it correct* to rewrite $(1)$ as:
$$\mathbb I :{\boldsymbol \sigma} + {\bf S} \, [{\bf S}:{\boldsymbol \sigma}] = {\bf C} $$ 
$$[\mathbb I + {\bf S} \otimes {\bf S}]:{\boldsymbol \sigma} = {\bf C} $$ 
and finally 
$${\boldsymbol \sigma} = [\mathbb I + {\bf S} \otimes {\bf S}]^{-1}:{\bf C} $$ 
**?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\s{\sigma}\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}\def\br#1{\big(#1\big)}
$Fully contract each term of the equation with $S,\,$ then solve for the scalar $\br{S:\s}$
$$\eqalign{
C &= \s+S\BR{S:\s} \\
{S:C} &= \BR{S:\s}\BR{\o+S:S} \\
{S:\s} &= \LR{\frac{S:C}{\o+S:S}} \\\\
}$$
Substitute this result into the original equation to recover $\s$
$$\eqalign{
\s &= C-\LR{\frac{S:C}{\o+S:S}}S \\\\
}$$
Note that
$$\eqalign{
&\BR{S:S} = \big\|S\big\|_F^2\;\ge\;0 \\
&\BR{\o+S:S}\;\ge\;\o \\
}$$
so the denominator is always $\ge\o\,$ and can *never* equal zero.

Answer (score 1):

If the following computations of coordinates on an orthonormal basis are correct, then
$$
\left[(\boldsymbol{\sigma} : {\bf S}){\bf S}\right]_{ij} = (\sigma_{ab}S_{ab})S_{ij} .
$$
In counterpart,
$$
\left[(({\bf S} \otimes {\bf S}) : {\bf I})\cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma}\right]_{ij} = (S_{aa})S_{ib}\sigma_{bj},
$$
which suggests that the factorization through $\boldsymbol\sigma$ is incorrect.

Let us assume that the vector space is $\Bbb R^3$. In the particular case where $\bf{S} = \alpha I$, the equation $(1)$ rewrites as
$$
\boldsymbol{\sigma} + \alpha^2 \text{tr}\boldsymbol{\sigma}\, {\bf I} = {\bf C} .
$$
Taking the trace, one has $(1+3\alpha^2)\,\text{tr}\boldsymbol{\sigma} = \text{tr}{\bf C}$, i.e.
$$
\boldsymbol{\sigma} = {\bf C} - \frac{\alpha^2\text{tr}{\bf C}}{1+3\alpha^2}\, {\bf I} ,
$$
but this works only for $\bf{S} = \alpha I$.
In the general case, I don't know if $(1)$ can be inverted under some conditions, and if there is a method to do so.

**Edit:** The proposed factorization looks fine. However, it may be not very useful in practice (how to compute the inverse of a fourth-order tensor with respect to the double-dot product?). One may have a look to related posts [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1624955/418542),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2275151/418542)].

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes these are 2nd order tensors. Is factorization through \sigma possible via any other way? I can form 9 equations (as tensors on both sides of the tensor-equation have 9 components), from that system of linear equations, I can calculate the components of  \sigma . however when writing the equations in the concise mathematical way, i can not find any proper way of doing so.

Comment: I have modified the question to include another possibility which does not requires S=\alpha I.  Can you kindly comment about the soundness of that approach?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the related posts. Is there any set of requirements which must be fulfilled by a fourth order tensor to have a unique inverse?

Comment: The related posts provide already some useful information on that question. If in your opinion there is something missing, then just ask a new question!