# About the notation $A:B$

Tags: tensor-products

Let $A^\left(n\right)$ and $B^\left(n\right)$ be two $n-$order tensors. In a physics paper, I've encountered the notation
$$
A^\left(n\right):B^{\left(n\right)}
$$
where it is said that " $:$ stands for full contraction of indexes". I've encountered this notation in all related papers. Can someone explain to me what is the meaning of that ? Is that a notation that is the same as $\otimes$ for tensor contraction product ? If yes, why is it called "full contraction of indexes" ?

The thing is this "product" remains unclear for me and no explanations are given. I will provide more informations if it's needed.

Comment: Might be related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275151/4th-order-tensors-double-dot-product-and-inverse-computation

Answer (score 1):

I understand it as
$$
A^\left(n\right):B^{\left(n\right)}
= A^{ijk\cdots} B_{ijk\cdots}
$$